# Access Typescript variable value in javascript inside Angular 2 Component

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have written a reusable component in Angular 2 to display the `Summernote` WYSIWYG editor in my application. That component accepts 3 input parameters which are being set as attributes for a rendered `textarea` as id, name and last one used as the body. My problem is that within this component I am initializing the Summernote plugin and creating the editor. **Here, I do not want to hard code the selector name and want the dynamic values that the component received as the input parameters to the component.** Relevant code is as follows.

```
import {Component, ElementRef, OnInit, EventEmitter, Input, Output, Inject, ComponentRef} from '@angular/core';
import {Http} from '@angular/http';

declare var $: any;

@Component({
    selector: 'editor',
    template: `<textarea id="{{eid}}" name="{{ename}}" class="form-control">{{body}}</textarea>`
})

export class EditorComponent {

    @Input() body: string;
    @Input() eid: string;
    @Input() ename: string;
    @Output() onContentChanged: EventEmitter<any>;

    constructor(){}

    ngAfterViewInit()
    {
        $(document).on("pageLoaded", function (){
            console.log("pageLoaded");

                $("#body").summernote({
                    height: '200px',
                    callbacks: {
                        onChange: function(contents, $editable) {
                            $("#body").val(contents);
                        }
                    }
                });

        });
    }
}
```

Here, you can see that I have used `$("#body")` twice inside the `ngAfterViewInit` block. I want this to be replaced by the `eid` variable. I have tried `{{eid}}` but it doesn't work and throws the following error in browser console.

`EXCEPTION: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #{{eid}}`

`this.eid` can't be used here either since we're inside the javascript method and not typescript.

I'm using this component in my other view file as a directive.

`<editor [body]="page.body" eid="body" ename="body"></editor>`

The `template` block in component is set properly with dynamic values. Only the javascript part is my issue.

Is there any other way I'm missing here?

P.S. So far it works great. I just want to make the initialization fully dynamic, so that I can use it anywhere with different IDs.

Comment: Have you tried the old method of binding the context into the function so that you can access this and all its variables?

Comment: @Katana24 Can you please be more specific and provide an example please?

Comment: Have a look at this article https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind - Also - why are using Jquery in there?

Comment: your reference article is something completely off the topic. I'm talking about Typescript vs Javascript scopes here. I'm using jQuery here because Angular 2 final version has just released and the plugin I'm using is not ported to Angular 2 yet. So, I have to live with it and use the jQuery version.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try using arrow functions instead of **function** to keep the same context.

```js
  $(document).on("pageLoaded", () => {
            console.log("pageLoaded");

                $(this.eid).summernote({
                    height: '200px',
                    callbacks: {
                        onChange: (contents, $editable) => {
                            $(this.eid).val(contents);
                        }
                    }
                });

        });
    }
```

Comment: It's a lovely answer. I didn't know we could mix Typescript and Javascript using arrow functions to keep the same context. It did partially solve my issue and gave me the value I needed but I'm also having tons of exceptions now. Major one says repeatedly `Zone already loaded`. And my editor is not initialized on the textarea but on the whole page. i.e. whole page is inside the Editor.

Comment: Alright, my bad... actually my `this.eid` variable contained the text "body" so `$(this.eid)` became `$("body")` on runtime. Which made it initialize on the body element. I just changed it to `$("#" + this.eid)` and everything is great now.